# Uploading mxd to ArcGIS Online with Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-online, mxd, error-000732, arcgis-python-api

I need to create a Python script to upload an MXD to AGOL. I have created an script in **arcpy** to create a **service definition** file (*.sd) from the mxd. I have not been able to upload the sd to AGOL unless ArcMap is open. I use the following code:

```
arcpy.SignInToPortal_server("AGOL_USER", "AGOL_PASS", "http://www.arcgis.com/")
arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd, "My Hosted Services", service)
```

I get the following error:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Server: Dataset My Hosted Services does not exist or is not suppoted
Failed to execute (UploadServiceDefinition).
```

I have been able to upload the service document file using **ArcGIS API for Python**:

```
gis = GIS("https://XXXX.maps.arcgis.com", "AGOL_USER", password)
item = gis.content.add({}, "XXX.sd")
published_item = item.publish(overwrite=True)
```

a) How can I upload the service definition file to AGOL using arcpy? The script needs to be run scheduled, so I cannot have ArcMap open

b) Would be posible to merge **arcpy** code with ArcGIS API for Python?

Comment: Seems to have been posted by same user at https://community.esri.com/thread/221706-upload-mxd-to-agol-with-python where it is currently unanswered.